# Removing class Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to remove the class of `.active` on `$(document).ready`.

#### CSS

```
.active { color: "red" }
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="item step-00">
    test
</div>
<div class="item step-0 active">
    test1
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item step-0 active").removeClass("active");
   $(".item step-00").addClass("active");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skX7E/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `.` before each class like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item.step-0.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".item.step-00").addClass("active");
});
```

or you could simplify to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item.step-0, .item.step-00").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Edit: You need to enable jquery in your fiddle. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skX7E/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item.step-0.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".item.step-00").addClass("active");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/skX7E/6/